# Detecting/intercepting insertion of <img> into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

We're using a third-party analytics reporting script provided by this analytics company. It adds a 1x1 pixel image into the DOM with reporting data in the URL of the image.

Is there any way for me to monitor the DOM and intercept this `<img>` element and change its "src" attribute before the browser requests the image?

Sounds like a really odd thing to do, I know, but there's a feature we'd like to hack onto this reporting script (the script is obsfucated).

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but have you tried live? like: $('img').live('load',function(){alert("Image added to DOM!");});

Comment: @Adam: I'm pretty sure that would drive you crazy in short order, especially considering a page can have literally hundreds of images on it.

Comment: @Robusto True but you could filter the selector by class, id, src, or size, I was just suggesting using live to attach the load event, but I'm not sure if that gets called when an image is added to the DOM and if so when.

Comment: Are the dimensions specified within the img tag? Have you inspected the DOM with firebug or such?

Comment: The third-party script actually removes it from the DOM immediately after it loads, so I don't know anything about it except for what I can see in the Net->Images panel of Firebug. :(

Comment: Hmm, Adam, if there was an event that fired before "load", that's a great idea, but unfortunately, "load" fires after the image has been downloaded and rendered.

Comment: Waiting for the `load` event of the image surely defeats the object, which is to prevent the image from being requested at all. An image's `load` event is only fired once the image has fully downloaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you simply won't be able to achieve this in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In non-IE browsers, you can detect the insertion of a DOM node by using the `DOMNodeInserted` event. I don't know if the browser will have made the HTTP request by the time the event is fired; it appears not to in Firefox from a quick test. Since this doesn't work in IE, this may not be an acceptable solution anyway.

```
document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(evt) {
    var node = evt.target;
    if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == "IMG") {
        node.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/be21766f09e0e5fd3a2f8cc721ceba2e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"; // Your gravatar
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go. I don't know how useful it will be, but I felt like tinkering and it somewhat accounts for the scenario whereby the third party purposefully incorporates a delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// match an image with specific dimension, return it
function imgNinja() {
    var $img =  $("img").filter(function() {
        return ($(this).height() == 1 && $(this).width() == 1);
    });
    return $img;
}

// periodically execute this to check for matches
function keepSeeking() {
    $img = imgNinja();
    if($img.length) {
        alert('found it');
        clearInterval(i);
        // do something with image
    }
}

// insert a fake into the DOM at a bit of an interval
function addNastyImage() {
   var $invader = $('<img src="foo.jpg" height="1px" width="1px"/>'); 
    $('html').append($invader);
}


setTimeout(addNastyImage, 5000);
var i = setInterval(keepSeeking, 1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NyEdE/3/

Comment: If the pixel is added as part of a metrics suite, it likely loads before the DOM's ready event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

If the third-party script uses a method (like `.appendChild`) to add the element to the document, you can probably do this by replacing that method of the relevant object with your own function.

That would have the advantage of working in all browsers, and I think you would only generate one HTTP request (for the changed URL, not for the original one).

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Adam suggested:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img[src='http://example.com/example.gif']").attr('src','http://example.com/new_src.gif');
});
```

Comment: This won't work. Adam suggested the use of `live`, which applies to elements created in the future. This script only analyzes elements currently in the DOM.

Comment: If the <img> is added via javascript after the DOM has loaded, I agree, he'd want to use live.  However, the selector he'd want to use would be quite similar to this.