# JavaScript: how to change image source without issuing two HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, dom

Here's the code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <img src="lowres/image123.jpg">
</div>
```

**PREMISSES**:
The `<img>` element is generated by a proprietary system backend and uses a low resolution image as source. I can only operate on it using pure javascript (no jquery!).

**I NEED TO** change de `src` attribute to a high resolution version located in a external server, eg.: `src="//cdn.provider.com/highres/image123.png"` (images have the same name but different locations).

**THE PROBLEM**: doing it after `<img>` insertion into DOM issues 2 (two) HTTP requests, one for the lowres image and other for the highres - and I have *lots* of images on the page!

In order to **FIX IT**, I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate `<img>` just before its insertion into DOM to change `src` appropriately, for example by intercepting an `<img>` event *"beforeInsertion"* or an event *"afterInsertion"* of the `<div>` wrapping it.

Cheers!

**UPDATE 1**: to make things clear: 1) I don't have accesss to the backend/server side; 2) I don't want to display the low resolution image, just the high resolution; 3) I dont' know the file name in advance, I need to get it from the `<img>` and append it to the path of the high resolution version stored in the CDN (both images have the same name); and 4) I can do it with the code bellow, but at the cost of **TWO** HTTP requests, which is what I want to avoid and what has motivated this question! ;)

```
var img = document.getElementById("wrapper").childNodes[0];
img.src = getHighResolutionImagePath(img.src);
```

Comment: What are the requirements for when the user receives a low or high-res image? Can you use CSS media queries and a background-image instead of an actual `img` tag?

Comment: Are you going to change all the external resources on the page, or only a few. If it's all, you might be able to do something with the <base> element https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base (if you control the <head> of your page)

Comment: @RGraham: 1. no requirements, I just need to replace and old and deprecated image, and I don't have backend access to change it in the server side, to a new version with higher resolution (I don't know if I fully understood your question). 2. I think media queries won't be helpful. 3. The `<img>` in the code snippet, with the lowres image, is generated by the backend and I have no control over it. However, I can use background-image to display the highres version.

Comment: @Xavier: I don't control the `<head>` and only some of the images are stored in the CDN.

Comment: If you don't have access to the backend how are you going to insert the javascript? See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410613/javascript-detecting-intercepting-insertion-of-img-into-dom helps. You'd need to add the javascript just after the body element so that it is run straight away.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this article, the problem is exactly the same. However, since it uses jquery and doesn't work in IE, I won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change url before adding `<img>` tag to document (e.g in server side script). Browser will get image from given url as soon as it'll receive tag, so it's not possible to replace it then. Especially that js will execute after getting all elements used on website.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the backend/server side.

Comment: @tdelboni So there is no option to do that. Low res image is already downloaded when your script is starting execution.

Answer (score 0):

When you're developing an app for retina displays and you want to let the browser know it's a high resolution image, you would append "@2x" to the picture name, like so:

> background-image: url('../img/logo2@2x.png');

Try that and see if the browser adopts the same policy.

Source: http://benfrain.com/how-to-serve-high-resolution-website-images-for-retina-displays-new-ipadiphone4/

Comment: As a don't know the file name in advance, I would still have to get it from the `<img>` element...

Comment: Ah, very true. I hope you discover a solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

You must listen to mutation events, specifically `DOMNodeInserted`

Full documentation is available at [MDN > Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

Once you have detected that an image as been added (you must filter the proper image type) you can replace the source for the one you want.

A small snippet taken from MDN:

```
element.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
// ...
}, false);
```

Beware that performance will be greatly degraded